# How to insert text between two figures?

Tags: floats, positioning

How to insert text between two figures or images in LaTeX? I have this code

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{1.jpg}
    \caption{Resala's Donation Page.}
\end{figure}

and for the volunteering activities, they do record all their activities...

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{2.jpg}
    \caption{Resala's Project Page.}
\end{figure}
```

but what happens is the text is placed before the first image and all images are placed at the end of the page.

Comment: Float positioning is a common issue with LaTeX beginners. We have some good answers for that. Please see: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017), [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275) as well as the question linked to them on the right sidebar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use only one `figure` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
{\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{1.jpg}
\caption{Resala's Donation Page.}\par\medskip
}
and for the volunteering activities, they do record all their activities...\par\bigskip
{\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{2.jpg}
\caption{Resala's Project Page.}\par
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: unfortunately, the caption for figure 1 looks like it's a "title" for the text, and that whole block looks like it belongs to figure 2, while the caption for figure 2 is quite lonely.  some spacing adjustments would improve the situation.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes. I adjusted the vertical spacing; hopefully, it's better now.

Comment: it's working fine but the vertical spacing isn't adjusted, the content still needs to be a little further than the image

Comment: @FadyKamal in my code, change `\par\medskip` and/or `\par\bigskip` for something like `\par\vskip30pt` (change the `30pt` length according to your needs).

Answer (score 7):

You're looking to prevent LaTeX from judging where to place floats (such as tables and figures), right? To achieve this objective, you could use the `float` [!] package and use the `[H]` placement directive provided by that package to freeze/fix in place the respective floats.

Note that this approach cannot guarantee that the two "floats" and the text between them will actually fit on that page. If there's not enough space left on the page, the second "float" and possibly even the text between the floats will be placed on the next page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{1.jpg}
    \caption{Resala's Donation Page.}
\end{figure}
\noindent
and for the volunteering activities, they do record all their activities\dots

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{2.jpg}
    \caption{Resala's Project Page.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your help is much appreciated