# Add Text After a Second Figure

Tags: floats

I am simply trying to have two figures in one section on one page with text in between.
In the below example the PDF result is text1, picture1, text2, text3 which is not what I intended.

```
Text1

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{picture1.jpg}
  \caption{A boat.}
  \label{fig:boat1}
\end{figure}

Text2

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{picture2.jpg}
  \caption{A boat.}
  \label{fig:boat1}
\end{figure}

Text3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: the only purpose of the `figure` environment is to allow the figures to be moved, and since you have used `[h]` you are preventing the figures being placed at top or bottom of the page or on a page of their own so it is quite likely that they can not be placed anywhere (you may see a warning that latex has changed this to `ht` to make it possible to output them somewheer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert text between two figures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116449/how-to-insert-text-between-two-figures)

Comment: Use `\begin{figure}[H]` and put `\usepackage{float}` in the preamble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DavidCarlisle has already pointed out in a comment, you're not using the `figure` environments as they were intended to be used.

Since you apparently don't want the graphs to "float" (in the LaTeX-specific sense of the word), you'd be better off encasing the `\includegraphics` directives in `center` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}  % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{caption}  % for \captionof macro
\usepackage{graphicx} % for \includegraphics macro
\begin{document}

Text1

\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{picture1.jpg}
  \captionof{figure}{A boat.}
  \label{fig:boat1}
\end{center}

Text2

\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{picture2.jpg}
  \captionof{figure}{Another boat.}
  \label{fig:boat2}
\end{center}

Text3

\end{document}
```